# How to show equality of these ratios?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, polygons

In the convex pentagon *ABCDE*, side *BC* is parallel to diagonal *AD* and *AE* is parallel to *BD*. Points *N* and *M* bisect sides *ED* and *CD* respectively. *x, y, z* are the altitudes to triangles $\triangle MNQ, \triangle MND$ and $\triangle ABQ$ respectively.
How would you show that ratios $\dfrac{AB}{MN} = \dfrac{2AB}{EC}$ and $\dfrac{(x+y)}{z} $ are equal? Or what are your first thoughts/approaches here?
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? show your attempts.

Comment: I must admit that I’m quite new to this somewhat more advanced geometry… I tried utilizing the ratios of diagonals of the two trapezoids _ABDE_ and _ABCD_ but couldn‘t get any further with that. I‘m not quite sure how to approach this

Comment: I noticed 2 things. Firstly, $2MN = EC$ and $\measuredangle EAD = \measuredangle BDA = \measuredangle CBD$. I'm not sure if they're useful though.

Comment: The equality of ratios follows from the equality of area:  _[ABQ]_ = _[MDNQ]_. But I thought showing the ratio equality might be easier

Comment: what is the source of this problem?

Comment: The initial exercise was to prove that *MDNQ* and *ABQ* have the same area